# How to pass php variable in facebook invite link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i build website in that i need to add functionality invite friends from facebook. so i used following code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

    <div class="invite-fb">
                       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
                        <div id="fb-root"><p>Invite On Facebook</p>
                        <p><input type="button" onclick="invitefriends()" value="Facebook" /></p>
                        </div>   
                    </div>  



<script>
 function invitefriends()
      {   
            var fblink ='<?php echo $_SESSION['url']; ?>';
             FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

              FB.ui({
                  method: 'send',
                  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                    link: fblink
                  });

     }


</script>
```

but when i am executing this code it is giving me

**This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.**

Can any one help me one this how to achieve my goal.

thank you.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is a _relative_ path – as the `link` parameter you have to pass a _full, absolute_ URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REQUEST_URI is not the full link, it's only the URI of the page ( from the first slash after the base URL to the end of the URL ).
You'll have to build your url with $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] and prepending it with http:// or https:// depending on the protocol used